# Django Models auto_now saving same time as auto_now_add

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model

Django models issue. I add these 2 fields in almost every model to store created (auto_now_add=True) and updated datetime (auto_now=True).

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

### Problem

Problem is when I create a new row in a table using Django, created_at field gets populated with current datetime (which is fine) but its updated_at field also gets populated on first time creation.

Does that make sense? From an end user's point of view, I only created a record but never updated it but in database its updated time is also updated since data is inserted first time in a row (happens whenever you insert a new row). So, when a user views the record, system will show created_at and updated_at exactly same.

Comment: define updated_at: should it be like "something changed since last time"? and then, yep, it makes sense. Imagine that you are searching for all updated field, do you expect new value to be excluded or included? I feel included.
also, it's just a on the fly answer since the models.py is missing

Comment: @Carlo Yes, its the time when something changed in your table's row but why does it enters current datetime when you CREATE the row not UPDATE it. Shouldn't it stay empty when I create a new record (just creating a new record not updating it) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** when you create an object for the first time, both `created_at` and `updated_at` will be filled with values, accordingly to the code you crafted.

- The `auto_now_add` will set the `timezone.now()` only when the instance is created.
- The `auto_now` will update the field every time the save method is called.

However, both functions the same way by triggering the field update event with `timezone.now()`.

This means that when you create an object for the first time, both `created_at` and `updated_at will` be filled with values.

But, the next time you save that object, the created_at will remain the same, while the updated_at will call the `timezone.now()`.

The options auto_now_add, auto_now, and default are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.

Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/